# How to pass extra arguments to Keycloak's EvaluationContext?

Tags: keycloak

Is is possible to pass extra attributes via [The Evaluation Context](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#the-evaluation-context)? I'd like to create a JavaScript policy based on a geolocation info, where the (webapp) client passes the country code as a runtime attribute. So the policy would look like this:

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var attr = context.getAttributes();
var geoloc = attr.getValue('notkc.country_of_origin'); //gets passed to the auth request

if (VALID_COUNTRIES.indexOf(geoloc)) > -1) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

There was [a mailing list discussion back in February 2017](http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Additional-attributes-for-an-authorization-request-td2571.html) where one of the core team members (Pedro) said it wasn't possible at the moment but was being considered. Half a year later there was [a JIRA issue 5457](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5457) which says it could be obtained from the resource permission, but I don't see how that would work.

**UPDATE**: the support was added at some point via [Claim Information Point](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_claim_information_point): it can push information into the context using various sources (HTTP request, ...).

Comment: Claim Information Points appeared in version 4.0.0, according to the release notes. Did you get these to work for your use case?